# PyQt5 - Can't adjust pixmap size within layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFormLayout, QGroupBox, QLabel, 
  QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea
  import sys 
  from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setGeometry(0,0,1920, 1080)

    self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
    self.image_one = "steinsgate.jpg"
    self.image_two = "kimi.jpg"
    
    draggableImage = DraggableImage(imgPath=self.image_one, parent=self)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(draggableImage)

    draggableImage = DraggableImage(imgPath=self.image_two, parent=self)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(draggableImage)



class DraggableImage(QtWidgets.QLabel):
  def __init__(self, imgPath=None, parent=None):
    super(DraggableImage, self).__init__()
    self.setParent(parent)
    self.drag_start_pos = None
    self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(imgPath))
    self.setObjectName(imgPath)
    
    #SetGeometry and Scaled contents are not working, image is displayed and normal resolution.
    self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 133, 1639, 2423))
    self.setText("")
    self.setScaledContents(True)
```

The pixmaps are not changing when I add a setGeometry or set scale command. I think this is because they are in the a layout where the sizes set are more important so the commands I try are not working. How should I get them to work? And on a side-note - if I was to add a scroll area where should it be placed since it never opens on the same window as my images, is this because of the layout as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably trying to use a modified `pyuic` generated file (or mimicking its behavior), which is something that should never be done. In any case, you should provide us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you're trying to achieve, otherwise it would be almost impossible to help you.

Comment: @musicamante I've rewritten the code so it shows just the issue I have

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear. Since you're using a layout manager, using `setGeometgry` doesn't make much sense, as it would set their position and adjust their size according to each QLabel sizeHint. What is the expected result?

Comment: @musicamante I want to adjust the size of the pixmaps but how do I do that when I'm using a layout cause like you say the setGeometry doesn't work